# Mask image loaded in UV Editing window doesn't show up under Gaussian Blur modifier mask source in Video Editing tab

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video, uv-image-editor, masking

Basically the title. I've been loosely following a YouTube tutorial where the mask was created within Blender if it makes a difference. The mask was created in a separate image editing program and is a PNG image. Here's the UV Editing window if it helps: [image: UV editing window]

And here's what I see when trying to use it as a mask:

[image: mask source menu]

Any help on how to get this mask image to show up in my modifiers pane would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have opened the *UV editor* window

1. Open image editor window, shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>
2. At around top there should be written something View(next to Image Editor button), click it and change it to Mask
3. You can then create a mask by clicking +     New button.

[image]